# how to apply themes for devexpress scheduler

Tags: javascript, devexpress

I am new to devexpress,I am trying to implement asp.net mvc scheduler.I have defined the scheduler like

```
@Html.DevExpress().Scheduler(
    settings => {
        settings.Name = "scheduler";
        settings.CallbackRouteValues = new { Controller = "Scheduler", Action =  "GroupingPartial" };
        settings.ActiveViewType = SchedulerViewType.Day;
        settings.Start = new DateTime(2010, 7, 13);
        settings.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
        settings.Views.DayView.ResourcesPerPage = 2;

        settings.Views.WorkWeekView.ResourcesPerPage = 2;

        settings.Views.WeekView.ResourcesPerPage = 2;

        settings.Views.MonthView.ResourcesPerPage = 2;

        settings.Views.TimelineView.ResourcesPerPage = 2;

        settings.GroupType = (SchedulerGroupType)Session["GroupType"];

        settings.Storage.Resources.Assign(SchedulerDemoHelper.DefaultResourceStorage);

    }).Bind(Model.Appointments, Model.Resources).GetHtml()
```

how to apply theme for the scheduler?Is there any additional code added to web.config file?

Answer (score 0):

To apply a theme, you should perform the following two actions:

1. Register stylesheet files required for a theme(s) you want to use in an application(Use the [ExtensionsFactory.RenderStyleSheets](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebMvcUIExtensionsFactory_RenderStyleSheetstopic) method to register required theme stylesheet files.).
2. To apply theme to scheduller extension individually, use the [SettingsBase.Theme](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebMvcSettingsBase_Themetopic) property (works for both DevExpress and standard ASP.NET theming approaches)

You can read the detailed instruction on applying themes in the following help-article: [Applying Themes](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9143).

Comment: I tried like new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Scheduler,theme="Aqua" } but it is throwing error that Aqua theme is not Found.

Comment: @charan make sure that the theme is exists within the Theme_App project folder (to copy theme files from a theme assembly to the App_Themes folder you can use ASPxThemeDeployer tool)